# Remove the is required on click event in zend framework

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, textbox

I am using zend framework. I have a text field which is a compulsory field. I also have a checkbox. On click of checkbox i want to hide the textfield and remove the compulsory attribute of the textfield. 
For now I am usign jquery to simply hide the div in which the text field is placed but i got validation error as the text field is compulsory field.

Is it possible to remove the compulsory attribute of textbox on any event.

Could anyone please help me on this issue. Thanks.

Comment: What is this `compulsory attribute`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can really make Zend form validators be dependent on JavaScript events.
But what you can do is overwrite `form::isValid()` method, so that validators would be removed based on the data submitted

```
public function isValid($data)
{
    if ( empty($data['checkboxField']) ) {
        $this->getElement('textField')->removeValidator('NotEmpty');
    }
    return parent::isValid($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can set `required` to `false` when instantiating your validator, for example:

```
$password1 = $this->addElement('password','password', array(
            'filters'  => array('StringTrim'),
            'validators' => array(array('StringLength', false, array(6, 20))),
            'required' => false,
            'label'  => 'Password: ',
            'description'  => 'Password between 6 and 20 characters'
));
```

Comment: I wanted the required to be false only in the case when the check box of the form is checked. When check box is not checked i need required to be true. Is it possible??